# SQL: Select certain rows with window functions in MySQL/MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, subquery, window-functions

My problem can be simplified to the following example:

```
create table dsort(dfrom date,dto date,pname varchar(10));
insert into dsort(dfrom,dto,pname) values(20180101,20180101,'Anja');
insert into dsort(dfrom,dto,pname) values(20190101,20191231,'Fred');
insert into dsort(dfrom,dto,pname) values(20190201,20190201,'Willy');
insert into dsort(dfrom,dto,pname) values(20190301,20190301,'John');
insert into dsort(dfrom,dto,pname) values(20191230,20200131,'Sepp');
insert into dsort(dfrom,dto,pname) values(20200201,20200202,'Leo');
```

Now I'm looking for an sql statement which selects all rows (ordered by `dfrom`) having a `dfrom` not between the `dfrom` and `dto` of any previously selected row, possibly using window functions to get informations on other rows, like this:

```
select dfrom,dto,pname from ...
```

resulting in:

```
dfrom          dto       pname
20180101       20180101  'Anja'
20190101       20191231  'Fred'
20200201       20200202  'Leo'
```

Can anyone give me the necessary sql statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest approach is `not exists`:

```
select d.*
from dsort d
where not exists (
    select 1
    from dsort d1
    where d.dfrom > d1.dfrom  and d.dfrom < d1.dto
)
```

Comment: Yes, for my simplified example this is a good solution. In reality, `dsort` stands for a huge select statement with several unions which I don't prefer to call twice, but maybe the optimizer doesn't really call it twice if I enter it twice like in Your solution?

Comment: @GeraldSchade: it is hard to tell wihout seeing your actual query. One idea: you could put your existing query in a CTE: `with dsort as (-- your big query --) select -- the above query --`

Comment: Thank You, that's it! (In Your code, d.from should be corrected to d.dfrom)